# Constantly search for an image by using Sikuli with Java

Tags: java, image, sikuli

I am making an Image Detection bot using the Sikuli API and I was wondering if anyone  knows how I can make it constantly scan for an image, then click on it? At the moment it will scan then click, but I want it to be constantly scanning.

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
int mil = MaxMillis;
boolean flagIsFound = false;

while (mil > 0 && flagIsFound != true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            mil -= 1000;
            System.out.println("wait for the image a sec");
            if (screen.exists(image) != null)
            {
                // found
                flagIsFound = true;
            }
        }
        if(flagIsFound == false)
        {
            throw new SikuliException(image + " not found for " + MaxMillis + " milliseconds");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to scan until it appears and then click on the image, or will the image recur, and you need it to click on the image every time it pops up? Either way, I think your solution is simple--

For scanning until it pops up, then clicking on it once, then no more scanning--

```
while not exists(yourImage):
    wait(1) #can also use sleep()
click(yourImage)
```

for continuing to scan and click again and again, wrap it in another 'while' statement, for example--

```
while True: 
    while not exists(yourImage):
        wait(1)
    click(yourImage)
    if (someConditionIsMet):
        break
```